# Submit a Keras training job to Google cloud

Tags: tensorflow, keras, gcloud, gcp-ai-platform-training

I am trying to follow this tutorial:
https://medium.com/@natu.neeraj/training-a-keras-model-on-google-cloud-ml-cb831341c196

to upload and train a Keras model on Google Cloud Platform, but I can't get it to work.

Right now I have downloaded the package from GitHub, and I have created a cloud environment with AI-Platform and a bucket for storage.

I am uploading the files (with the suggested folder structure) to my Cloud Storage bucket (basically to the root of my storage), and then trying the following command in the cloud terminal:

```
gcloud ai-platform jobs submit training JOB1 
 --module-name=trainer.cnn_with_keras 
 --package-path=./trainer 
 --job-dir=gs://mykerasstorage      
 --region=europe-north1         
 --config=gs://mykerasstorage/trainer/cloudml-gpu.yaml
```

But I get errors, first the *cloudml-gpu.yaml* file can't be found, it says "no such folder or file", and trying to just remove it, I get errors because it says the *--init--.py* file is missing, but it isn't, even if it is empty (which it was when I downloaded from the tutorial GitHub). I am Guessing I haven't uploaded it the right way.

Any suggestions of how I should do this? There is really no info on this in the tutorial itself.

I have read in another guide that it is possible to let gcloud package and upload the job directly, but I am not sure how to do this or where to write the commands, in my terminal with `gcloud` command? Or in the Cloud Shell in the browser? And how do I define the path where my python files are located?

Should mention that I am working with Mac, and pretty new to using Keras and Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue with the GPU is solved now, it was something so simple as, my google cloud account had GPU settings disabled and needed to be upgraded.

Comment: Happy to hear that the issue was resolved. Indeed, you need to have a paid account to use GPUs and also new projects have a global GPU quota applied which has to be changed. However, this should have thrown a quota warning/error in your case. For the sake of community, please accept your answer as the correct one and upvote mine if it helped you reach resolution.

Comment: Ah, of course! Im pretty new here so didn't now about these functions, hope I managed to upvote and declare solution now. Thank you very much for your help!
I also currently have another issue in my project, about loading pre-trained keras models on google cloud: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59927900/load-pre-trained-keras-model-for-continued-training-on-google-cloud

Answer (score 3):

I was able to follow the tutorial you mentioned successfully, with some modifications along the way.

I will mention all the steps although you made it halfway as you mentioned.

First of all create a Cloud Storage Bucket for the job:

```
gsutil mb -l europe-north1 gs://keras-cloud-tutorial
```

To answer your question on where you should write these commands, depends on where you want to store the files that you will download from GitHub. In the tutorial you posted, the writer is using his own computer to run the commands and that's why he initializes the gcloud command with `gcloud init`. However, you can submit the job from the Cloud Shell too, if you download the needed files there.
The only files we need from the [repository](https://github.com/Neeraj-Natu/keras-cloud-test) are the `trainer` folder and the `setup.py` file. So, if we put them in a folder named `keras-cloud-tutorial` we will have this file structure:

```
keras-cloud-tutorial/
├── setup.py
└── trainer
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── cloudml-gpu.yaml
    └── cnn_with_keras.py
```

Now, a possible reason for the `ImportError: No module named eager` error is that you might have changed the `runtimeVersion` inside the `cloudml-gpu.yaml` file. As we can read [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/14247#issuecomment-362112577), `eager` was introduced in Tensorflow 1.5. If you have specified an earlier version, it is expected to experience this error. So the structure of `cloudml-gpu.yaml` should be like this:

```
trainingInput:
  scaleTier: CUSTOM
  # standard_gpu provides 1 GPU. Change to complex_model_m_gpu for 4 GPUs
  masterType: standard_gpu
  runtimeVersion: "1.5"
```

*Note: "standard_gpu" is a [legacy machine type](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/machine-types#legacy-machine-types).*

Also, the `setup.py` file should look like this:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(name='trainer',
      version='0.1',
      packages=find_packages(),
      description='Example on how to run keras on gcloud ml-engine',
      author='Username',
      author_email='user@gmail.com',
      install_requires=[
          'keras==2.1.5',
          'h5py'
      ],
      zip_safe=False)
```

**Attention:** As you can see, I have specified that I want version `2.1.5` of `keras`. This is because if I don't do that, the latest version is used which has compatibility issues with versions of Tensorflow earlier than `2.0`.

If everything is set, you can submit the job by running the following command inside the folder `keras-cloud-tutorial`:

```
gcloud ai-platform jobs submit training test_job --module-name=trainer.cnn_with_keras --package-path=./trainer --job-dir=gs://keras-cloud-tutorial --region=europe-west1 --config=trainer/cloudml-gpu.yaml
```

*Note: I used `gcloud ai-platform` instead of `gcloud ml-engine` command although both will work. At some point in the future though, `gcloud ml-engine` will be deprecated.*

**Attention:** Be careful when choosing the region in which the job will be submitted. Some regions do not support GPUs and will throw an error if chosen. For example, if in my command I set the `region` parameter to `europe-north1` instead of `europe-west1`, I will receive the following error:

> ERROR: (gcloud.ai-platform.jobs.submit.training) RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED:
>   Quota failure for project . The request for 1 K80
>   accelerators exceeds the allowed maximum of 0 K80, 0 P100, 0 P4, 0 T4,
>   0 TPU_V2, 0 TPU_V3, 0 V100. To read more about Cloud ML Engine quota,
>   see https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/quotas.
>   - '@type': type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.QuotaFailure   violations:
>     - description: The request for 1 K80 accelerators exceeds the allowed maximum of
>         0 K80, 0 P100, 0 P4, 0 T4, 0 TPU_V2, 0 TPU_V3, 0 V100.
>       subject:

You can read more about the features of each region [here](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/regions#region_considerations) and [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/regions-zones/).

**EDIT:**

After the completion of the training job, there should be 3 folders in the bucket that you specified: `logs/`, `model/` and `packages/`. The model is saved on the `model/` folder a an `.h5` file. Have in mind that if you set a specific folder for the destination you should include the '/' at the end. For example, you should set `gs://my-bucket/output/` instead of `gs://mybucket/output`. If you do the latter you will end up with folders `output`, `outputlogs` and `outputmodel`. Inside `output` there should be `packages`. The job page link should direct to `output` folder so make sure to check the rest of the bucket too!

In addition, in the AI-Platform job page you should be able to see information regarding `CPU`, `GPU` and `Network` utilization:
[image: AI-Platform training job page screenshot]

Also, I would like to clarify something as I saw that you posted some related questions as an answer:

Your local environment, either it is your personal Mac or the Cloud Shell has nothing to do with the actual training job. You don't need to install any specific package or framework locally. You just need to have the Google Cloud SDK installed (in Cloud Shell is of course already installed) to run the appropriate `gcloud` and `gsutil` commands. You can read more on how exactly training jobs on the AI-Platform work [here](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/training-overview#how_training_works).

I hope that you will find my answer helpful.

Comment: Thank you for this! I did now try to run with the parameters you suggested, and now it works! Great. Only thing though, is now I can't find the trained model that is supposed ot be saved. The Job status has a link to Model location (the folder that I specified), but when I click it or look in the folder, there is no file there? Or anywhere else at my storage bucket.

Comment: Did you try to refresh the bucket by clicking in the "Refresh" button in the console? There should be 3 folders in the bucket that you specified: `logs/`, `model/` and `packages/`. If you set a specific folder for the destination you should include the '/' at the end. For example, you should set `gs://my-bucket/output/` instead of `gs://mybucket/output`. If you do the latter you will end up with folders `output`, `outputlogs` and `outputmodel`. Inside `output` there should be `packages`. The job page link should direct to `output` folder so make sure to check the rest of the bucket  too!

Comment: Found it :) Another question though, I think now it was only running on CPU, as I can only see CPU stats for the job, and nothing for the GPU. How do I control if it will train on GPU or CPU at google cloud?

Comment: @Tessmus You should be able to see GPU utilization information in the `GPU` tab on the AI-Platform job page. I have edited my answer with a screenshot on where you can find this along with the information provided in the previous comment.

Comment: Thank you very much for this! When looking at the GPU tab, there is nothing, only on the CPU tag, so it seems it is running on CPU, despite this flag "masterType: standard_gpu" in cloudml-gpu.yaml. It also took almost as long to train on google cloud as on my local macbook, so I think its definitely not running on GPU. Is there any other place than in the cloudml-gpu.yaml, that I can specify it running on the GPU? In the current run, I did in fact use the region europe-north, but didn't get any error message.

Comment: Training with GPU [is not available](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/regions#region_considerations) in region `europe-north1` for sure. You should receive an error if you tried to submit a job with a config file like the `cloudml-gpu.yaml`. You should be able to confirm that `standard_gpu` was selected for the job if you click on the "SHOW JSON" button next to "Training Input" in the job page (visible in my screenshot). Could you check this please and let me know? Could you also test the job in a region with available K80 GPUs (ex. "europe-west1")

Comment: The "SHOW JSON" next to training input shows nothing on the GPU. I have now also tried running the job with region "europe-west1", both as flag for the job, and I also created a new storage bucket with region europe-west1- Still the job runs only on CPU, as I can see a curve there, but no curve on the GPU. And it actually runs slower than on my own laptop.

Comment: Please make sure that the configuration YAML file that you are using is exactly like the one (`cloudml-gpu.yaml`) provided in my answer. Inside this file, `scaleTier` should be set to `CUSTOM` and `masterType` should be set to `standard_gpu`. You can also read [this](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/machine-types#scale_tiers) about the different options you have.

Comment: It is, here is an exact copy of what's in the cloudml-gpu.yaml file:
trainingInput:

  scaleTier: CUSTOM
  masterType: standard_gpu
  runtimeVersion: "1.5"

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work halfway now by not uploading the files but just running the upload commands from cloud at my local terminal... however there was an error during it running ending in "job failed"

Seems it was trying to import something from the TensorFlow backend called *"from tensorflow.python.eager import context"* but there was an ImportError: *No module named eager*

I have tried *"pip install tf-nightly"* which was suggested at another place, but it says I don't have permission or I am loosing the connection to cloud shell(exactly when I try to run the command).

I have also tried making a virtual environment locally to match that on gcloud (with Conda), and have made an environment with Conda with *Python=3.5, Tensorflow=1.14.0* and *Keras=2.2.5*, which should be supported for gcloud.

The python program works fine in this environment locally, but I still get the (ImportError: No module named eager) when trying to run the job on gcloud.

I am putting the flag  --python-version 3.5 when submitting the job, but when I write the command "Python -V" in the google cloud shell, it says Python=2.7. Could this be the issue? I have not fins a way to update the python version with the cloud shell prompt, but it says google cloud should support python 3.5. If this is anyway the issue, any suggestions on how to upgrade python version on google cloud?

It is also possible to manually there a new job in the google cloud web interface, doing this, I get a different error message: *ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement cnn_with_keras.py (from versions: none)* and *No matching distribution found for cnn_with_keras.py*. Where *cnn_with_keras.py* is my python code from the tutorial, which runs fine locally.

Really don't know what to do next. Any suggestions or tips would be very helpful!